# App statistics by email

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

One of my clients asked me to send a daily report (by email) with the number of downloads of their app. The Appcelerator platform statistics include information about the #downloads. I don't want to give the client access to the platform. 
W
hat is the best way to give the clients insight into their figures? Does the appcelerator platform has a approach for it or do I have to use an external statistics platform for it?

Any ideas?

Comment: Just use the statistics provided in the Play Store console for Android or iTunesConnect for iOS

Comment: You can use AppAnnie to gather some basic statistics and grant acces (sharing) to other users to view only their own apps. It's not possible to send a daily email from AppAnnie to the users (afaik) but I think you can use the AppAnnie API to build your own solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the stats from the platform in chart or table format. I just created a excel dashboard and PDF it it and send to them. I also programmed in the custom analytics regarding navigation and such and add that. I didn't like that Apple only calculates stats from users that opt in.